# Find the maximum of the value $\frac{\gcd(n,[n\sqrt{5}])}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: number-theory

For any postive integer $n$ find the maximum of the value
$$\dfrac{\gcd(n,\left \lfloor{n\sqrt{5}}\right \rfloor)}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Let $m=[n\sqrt{5}]$,then we have $n\sqrt{5}-1<m\le n\sqrt{5}$,it is said consider pell equation?

Comment: What is the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: if the Pell equation to be considered is $m^2-5n^2=1$, then it will give $gcd(n, \tfrac{5n^2}{m+1})$ for the numerator. It looks as though this could be helpful, but not entirely sure yet.

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1252290 gives a maximum of $\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inequality can be written as $$\sqrt5-\frac1n < \frac{m}n < \sqrt5 \implies \left| \sqrt5 - \frac{m}n \right| < \frac1n$$

so need good rational approximations to $\sqrt5$.  i.e, we need solutions to $5n^2-m^2=k$ for "small" positive $k$.  Now, what is "small"?  Note $\lfloor n\sqrt5 \rfloor = m \implies m^2 + k < (m+1)^2 \implies k < 2m+1$.

Further note that if $g = \gcd(m, n)$, we may write $m = gx, n = gy, k= g^2z$ for some positive $z$.  As we seek maximum of $g^2/n = g/y \approx \sqrt5 g/x$, we need to keep $x, y$ smallest while having largest possible $g$.  So write the equation as
$$x^2- 5y^2 = - z$$
where $0< z < 2x/g +1/g^2 \implies gz \le 2x \implies g/x \le 2/z$.  Clearly largest value then for $g/x$ is when $z=1$, so we try
$x^2-5y^2=-1$ first, which has the smallest solution $(2, 1)$.  Now with $g = 4$, and we get the maximum when $m = gx = 8, n = gy = 4$ to give max $\dfrac{\gcd(4, \lfloor 4\sqrt5\rfloor)}{\sqrt4} = 2$.